# How to use different cache control header for different filenames with .htaccess?

Tags: image, apache, .htaccess, caching, mod-rewrite

I am trying to allow caching of images that will never change (there will be only new images and those will have different URL already...)

BUT, there are 2 folders with images, name of which doesn't change, but their content does, these are:

```
*profile/mini*
*profile/thumb*
```

All other images can be cached by browser.

This was my attempt:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=691200 must-revalidate, public"
    <FilesMatch "profile/(mini|thumb)">
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0 no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"
        Header set Expires "Sun, 2 Feb 2014 17:00:00 GMT"
    </FilesMatch>
</FilesMatch>
```

but it doesn't work. Images placed in pfoile/thumb are being cached still, However when I changed it to:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)$">
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0 no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"
    Header set Expires "Sun, 2 Feb 2014 17:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>
```

images have been refreshed correctly. What am I missing? Is "nesting" of `FilesMatch` rules even allowed?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than nesting try two independent section of `FilesMatch`:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=691200 must-revalidate, public"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "profile/(mini|thumb)">
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0 no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"
    Header set Expires "Sun, 2 Feb 2014 17:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>
```